# Find 'spare' time in list of python datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of events.  Each event as a Start and End which are both datetime objects.  I now want a list of "spare time" events which is created off the existing events, for the purposes of display.  I hope that makes sense.  This is the best I can come up with so far.  Any help appreciated!

```
class Event():
    Start = datetime.datetime
    End = datetime.datetime
    Reserved = boolean

# create a couple of events with some spare time between them...

ev1 = Event()
ev1.Start = datetime.datetime(2011,1,1,5)
ev1.End = datetime.datetime(2011,1,1,6)
ev1.Reserved = True

ev2 = Event()
ev2.Start = datetime.datetime(2011,1,1,8)
ev2.End = datetime.datetime(2011,1,1,9)
ev2.Reserved = True

events = [ev1,ev2]

# sort the events list...

events.sort(key=lambda e: e.Start)

# create a 'spare time' event based on the existing events...

allevents = []

for event in events:
    spare = Event()
    spare.Start = events[events.index(event)-1].End+datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    spare.End = event.Start-datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    spare.Reserved = False
    allevents.append(spare)
    allevents.append(event)

allevents.sort(key=lambda e: e.Start)

for event in allevents:
    print str(event.Start), str(event.End), event.Reserved
```

So, this works, but I have yet to figure out how to stop and start the spare time at midnight, but before I do that, I want to know if I'm heading in the right direction to start with.  Or is there a much better way??  (There usually is!)..

MFB

Comment: -1  for the strange definition of the Event class. Heard of using a constructor like __init__()? What should those pointless assignments datetime.datetime do????

Comment: There is a missing square bracket in your code.

Comment: @mac - thank you.  @Sentinel - yes, I have much to learn.  Actually, in my real app, the events are declared as Elixir classes.  I rarely need to create Python classes, as you can tell.  I just did it this time so people like you could run the code straight away.  So if you have any insight re the subject of the post, great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it more this way - just to give you some more concepts (it needs more error handling, but for now it should just show the idea):

```
from datetime import datetime
class Venue(object):
    """Collection of events"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.events_list = []

    def add_events(self,*args):
        for e in args:
            self.events_list.append(e)

    def sort_list(self):
        self.events_list.sort(key=lambda e: e.start_date)

    def find_spare_times(self):
        self.sort_list()
        for event in self.events_list:
            yield event.start_date
            yield event.end_date

    def add_spare_events(self):
        l = list(self.find_spare_times())
        print l
        new_start,new_end = None, None
        for e in l[1:]:
            if new_start:
                new_end = e
                self.add_events(Event(new_start,new_end,res=False))
                new_start = None
            else:
                new_start = e
                new_end = None

    def get_events(self):
        return self.events_list

class Event(object):
    """Holds the data for an individual event"""
    def __init__(self,start_date, end_date,res=True):
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.reserved = res

# create a couple of events with some spare time between them...
def main():
    ev1 = Event(datetime(2011,1,1,5),datetime(2011,1,1,6))
    ev2 = Event(datetime(2011,1,1,8),datetime(2011,1,1,9))

    v = Venue()
    v.add_events(ev1,ev2)
    print v.get_events()
    v.add_spare_events()
    print v.get_events()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thank you.  This is very different and I have learned a lot from it.  It needs extending to get the 1 second incrementation going the way I have in my example, but you've opened my mind!  Cheers.